# How to call a macro from another worksheet.?

Tags: excel, vba

I have assigned a macro to a button in worksheet 2. I have created a new button in a new worksheet and now i want the same macro to run or call from worksheet 4.

Comment: You need to give more info. Are these Buttons Shapes, Form Controls or ActiveX Controls etc? Are the button click events in the sheet object or a module and are they Public or Private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...hmm....

Put your code in a module:

[image]

You can then call it from anywhere. If you were to add an ActiveX control to a sheet then you could just double click the button in design mode and amend the code to the following and it should work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Call CallMeFromAnyWorkSheet
End Sub
```